# SQL Query Optimization

Tags: sql, query-optimization, union, execution-time, cursors

I have this query which takes about 52 second to be executed I have been meaning to use Cursors or anyway that could help me to optimize the execution time

```
select * from (
select distinct 'Net Sales' Class,  SUM ( CAST(ROUND(ABS(dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.PTD_ACTUAL), 0) AS float)) over (partition by  CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.PERIOD_DATE, 112)) ) 
- (select distinct sum( CAST(ROUND(ABS(v.PTD_ACTUAL), 0) AS float)) over (partition by  CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10), v.PERIOD_DATE, 112)) )  from Trial_Balance_Variances v
inner join 
dbo.[P&L] p ON v.GL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = p.Code  where p.Category in('Sales Rebates')
and v.PERIOD_NAME = Trial_Balance_Variances.PERIOD_NAME
   ) Total,CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.PERIOD_DATE, 112)) AS DateKey
from Trial_Balance_Variances
inner join 
dbo.[P&L] ON dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.GL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = dbo.[P&L].Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Location AS l ON l.Code = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(50), dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.ACCOUNT_COMBINATION), 4, 2) where Category = 'Potash Sales (Gross)'

union 

SELECT distinct l.Class,  SUM ( CAST(ROUND(ABS(dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.PTD_ACTUAL), 0) AS float)) over (partition by  CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.PERIOD_DATE, 112)) )
+ (select distinct sum( CAST(ROUND(ABS(v.PTD_ACTUAL), 0) AS float)) over (partition by  CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10), v.PERIOD_DATE, 112)) ) from Trial_Balance_Variances v
inner join 
dbo.[P&L] p ON v.GL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = p.Code  where p.Category in('Change In Inventory','Freight','Dispatch')
and v.PERIOD_NAME = Trial_Balance_Variances.PERIOD_NAME
   ) Total
,  CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.PERIOD_DATE, 112)) AS DateKey from Trial_Balance_Variances 
inner join 
dbo.[P&L] ON dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.GL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = dbo.[P&L].Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Location AS l ON l.Code = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(50), dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.ACCOUNT_COMBINATION), 4, 2)
where Class='Cost of goods sold'  and Category not in ('Sales Rebates','Royalties','Potash Sales (Gross)','Interest Expense LTL','Interest Expense LTMed','Interest Expense Others'
,'Interest Income','(Gain)/Loss from Investment Jor','(Gain)/Loss from Investment N+B','Gain from Investment', 'EXC Gain from Investment' ,'D Gain from Investment ', 'Loss from Investment Jormag','Bank Charges','Other Revenues','Change In Inventory','Freight','Dispatch') 

union 

SELECT distinct l.Class,  SUM ( CAST(ROUND(ABS(dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.PTD_ACTUAL), 0) AS float)) over (partition by  CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.PERIOD_DATE, 112)) ) Total
,  CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.PERIOD_DATE, 112)) AS DateKey from Trial_Balance_Variances 
inner join 
dbo.[P&L] ON dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.GL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = dbo.[P&L].Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Location AS l ON l.Code = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(50), dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.ACCOUNT_COMBINATION), 4, 2)
where Class='Administration'  and Category not in ('Sales Rebates','Royalties','Potash Sales (Gross)','Interest Expense LTL','Interest Expense LTMed','Interest Expense Others'
,'Interest Income','(Gain)/Loss from Investment Jor','(Gain)/Loss from Investment N+B','Gain from Investment', 'EXC Gain from Investment' ,'D Gain from Investment ', 'Loss from Investment Jormag','Bank Charges','Change In Inventory','Freight','Dispatch','Other Revenues') 
union 

SELECT distinct l.Class,  SUM ( CAST(ROUND(ABS(dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.PTD_ACTUAL), 0) AS float)) over (partition by  CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.PERIOD_DATE, 112)) ) Total
,  CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.PERIOD_DATE, 112)) AS DateKey from Trial_Balance_Variances 
inner join 
dbo.[P&L] ON dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.GL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = dbo.[P&L].Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Location AS l ON l.Code = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(50), dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.ACCOUNT_COMBINATION), 4, 2)
where Class='Selling And Distribution Expenses'  and Category not in ('Sales Rebates','Royalties','Potash Sales (Gross)','Interest Expense LTL','Interest Expense LTMed','Interest Expense Others'
,'Interest Income','(Gain)/Loss from Investment Jor','(Gain)/Loss from Investment N+B','Gain from Investment', 'EXC Gain from Investment' ,'D Gain from Investment ', 'Loss from Investment Jormag','Bank Charges','Change In Inventory','Freight','Dispatch','Other Revenues')

union 


SELECT distinct l.Class,  SUM ( CAST(ROUND(ABS(dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.PTD_ACTUAL), 0) AS float)) over (partition by  CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.PERIOD_DATE, 112)) )
+ (select distinct sum( CAST(ROUND(ABS(v.PTD_ACTUAL), 0) AS float)) over (partition by  CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10), v.PERIOD_DATE, 112)) ) from Trial_Balance_Variances v
inner join 
   dbo.[P&L] p ON v.GL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = p.Code  where p.Category in('Interest Expense LTL','Interest Expense LTMed','Interest Expense Others'
,'Interest Income','(Gain)/Loss from Investment Jor','(Gain)/Loss from Investment N+B','Gain from Investment', 'EXC Gain from Investment' ,'D Gain from Investment ', 'Loss from Investment Jormag','Bank Charges','Other Revenues')
    and v.PERIOD_NAME = Trial_Balance_Variances.PERIOD_NAME and SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(50), v.ACCOUNT_COMBINATION), 4, 2) not in ('00','05')
   )
,  CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.PERIOD_DATE, 112)) AS DateKey from Trial_Balance_Variances 
inner join 
dbo.[P&L] ON dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.GL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = dbo.[P&L].Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Location AS l ON l.Code = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(50), dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.ACCOUNT_COMBINATION), 4, 2)
where Class='Others'  and
 Category not in ('Sales Rebates','Royalties','Potash Sales (Gross)','Change In Inventory','Freight','Dispatch')) x order by x.DateKey
```

Could anyone help me to solve this problem please?

Comment: Adding cursors to this will definitely ***NOT*** improve performance - quite the contrary! Avoid cursors if you ever can .....

Comment: Distincts... Everywhere

Answer (score 1):

`SUBSTRING()` is a scalar function, which means they need to run on every row that they get called for. If you can, either omit them or run them after you've reduced your recordset.

I don't believe you need to convert to an int to get this ordering to work the way you want it to in this SQL:

```
CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.Trial_Balance_Variances.PERIOD_DATE, 112))
```

remove the `convert(int,....)` part and see what happens.

`Distinct` is pretty inefficient at what it does. I'd recommend changing them all to group by. To help with that I'd suggest putting everything into a temp table, then doing your final select so you only need to do it once.

If you'd like any specific stuff, giving us some test data on [a Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) would help!

Comment: omg ! that helped like crazy . the execution time is only 10 seconds now .. thaks alot !!